# Reading Multi-index data frames in python to retain format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe.

When I load the data

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + 'doc.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index_col=[0,1])
```

It looks like this

```
Index    Index    A    B    C    D
0        AA       0.1  0.2  0.4  0.4
0        AB       0.0 -0.5  0.3  0.9
1        BB       0.4  0.6  1.2  0.8
1        BC       0.4  0.4  0.1  0.7
```

I hoped it would instead look like this

```
Index    Index    A    B    C    D
0        AA       0.1  0.2  0.4  0.4
         AB       0.0 -0.5  0.3  0.9
1        BB       0.4  0.6  1.2  0.8
         BC       0.4  0.4  0.1  0.7
```

How can i get it to look the above table by reading this file differently or merging the 1st index column.

Comment: Maybe `df = df.set_index('Index')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So some of my packages were outdated, as soon and I did an update this started to work correctly. Thanks everyone for input.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + 'doc.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index_col=[1,2])
```

And if that still fails, I'd just do:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + 'doc.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
# rename columns beforehand if desired
df.set_index(['Index', 'Index.1'], inplace=True)
```